# Are all the ports on 2016 MacBook Pro 13" the same speed?

Tags: macbook-pro, thunderbolt

I have a 2016 MacBook Pro 13" with 4 Thunderbolt 3 ports. I am connecting a TB3 dock from the back left port of the MacBook Pro but would like to use the right back port instead.

I read on the [eGPU forums](https://egpu.io/forums/) that there was some difference in the ports, but I can no longer find the post. Are all the ports on 2016 MacBook Pro 13" the same speed? Should I expect lesser bandwidth or performance (for example, data transfer speed) from one port vs another?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it turns out, there is a [support document published by Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207256) that directly **answers my question**:

> Late-2016 MacBook Pro models vary slightly in the data speeds they
>   provide to each Thunderbolt 3 port.
>
> MacBook Pro (15-inch, Late 2016) delivers full Thunderbolt 3
>   performance on all four ports.
>
> **MacBook Pro (13-inch, Late 2016, Four Thunderbolt 3 Ports) supports Thunderbolt 3 at full performance using the two left-hand ports. The
>   two right-hand ports deliver Thunderbolt 3 functionality, but have
>   reduced PCI Express bandwidth.**
>
> MacBook Pro (13-inch, Late 2016, Two Thunderbolt 3 Ports) delivers
>   full Thunderbolt 3 performance on both ports.

Therefore based on this, I will use the left-hand ports for my high bandwidth peripherals.

Comment: Aha! Good catch. Now you know.

Answer (score 2):

Mactracker specifies: *4 - up to 40 Gbps*

[Apple Support Document](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP748?locale=en_US) specifies even further:

*Four Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) ports with support for:*

- Charging
- DisplayPort
- Thunderbolt (up to 40 Gbps)
- USB 3.1 Gen 2 (up to 10 Gbps)

The key phrase here is **up to**. 40 Gbps is the *theoretical maximum* the MBP T-Bolt ports can provide, but most likely that speed is never fully attainable, nor sustainable, under normal usage.

Your milage may vary.